# Delta Encoding for large files - good implementation available?

Tags: c#

For my backup tool, I'm still looking for a good delta encoding algorithm, that can handle a binary file. Problem is, I've got pretty huge binary files, e.g. 600MB and up. So, it's pretty hard for a 32bit application to assign up to 10 Gig of RAM. Honestly, it's impossible.

So I looked at the csharp bsdiff implementation found [here](https://github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net). It's pretty cool, but loads the whole file into a byte array. So, does anyone now an implementation that can handle large files? I mean, REALLY large files?

Comment: Have a look at the [rsync algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running on a Windows environment, look at [Remote Differential Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373254.aspx).  It was developed as an improvement upon rsync with the premise you have a server and a client with similar versions of a file, with one being the "master", and you want to sync them together.

C# wrapper on the COM libraries can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/davidjade/rdc.net).

Comment: FYI, I implemented the [core RDC algorithm in pure C#](https://github.com/jklemmack/rdc.net).  Its not drop-in compatible, but it is a starting point for chunking and reporting semi-unique signatures.  This forms the basis of delta encoding.